# show quadratic forms $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ and $ x^2 - y^2 - z^2$ are equivalent over finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields, quadratic-forms

<del>Can I show the diagonal matrix (1,1,1) and (1,-1,-1) are equivalent over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_3$</del>

Can I show the quadratic forms $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ and $x^2 - y^2 - z^2$ are equivalent over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_3$

One way to phrase this is that $2\times 2$ matrices and Hamilton quaternions over $\mathbb{F}_3$ are the same as "quadratic spaces"

$$ 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 a + b & c + d \\
 -c +d & a-b
 \end{array} \right]  \leftrightarrow 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 a + b i& c + d i\\
 -c +d i & a-bi 
 \end{array}\right]
$$

I am trying to do this as elementary algebra and write down the change of basis that turns $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2$ into $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2$

These two are certainly equivalent over $\mathbb{C}$ since $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ where $p = 4k+1$, e.g. $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_5$ but not $\mathbb{Q}_7$

<del>It's not the case that (1,1) is similar to (-1,-1) I don't think</del>

Serre "Course on Arithmetic" says only two quadratic forms up to equivalence.  So $x^2+y^2$ and $-x^2-y^2$ are similar.

---

After a while I came up with:

$$ (x +y)^2+(x -y)^2= 2x^2+2y^2=-x^2-y^2$$

So it is possible to turn this quadratic form into it's negative using invertible linear transformation.  Am I mistaken to phrase this as,  the two diagonal matrices (1,1) and (1,-1) are similar over the finite field with three elements $\mathbb{F}_3$?

If $p =4k +1$ then $\sqrt{-1}\in \mathbb{F}_p $ such as $2^2=-1$.

However I could not solve the next cases $p =7, 11,19,23,31,...$

Comment: How is the "equivalent" you're speaking about here defined?

Comment: "The diagonal matrix $(1,1,1)$" is the identity matrix, and is "equivalent" (similar) only to itself.

Comment: As quadratic spaces are mentioned I am fairly sure that the question is about equivalence of the related quadratic forms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen are the diagonal matrices themselves not similar over $\mathbb{F}_3$ ?  I can take that part out.

Comment: Two quadratic forms are equivalent iff their (symmetric) matrices $A$ and $A'$ satisfy the relation $PAP^T=A'$ for some invertible matrix $P$. The matrices are similar, iff they satisfy the relation $PAP^{-1}=A'$ for some invertible $P$. So equivalence of forms is distinct from similarity of matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Every nonsingular quadratic form $Q$ of dimension $\geq2$ over a finite field $\mathbf F_q$ of characteristic $\neq2$ is equivalent to a diagonal quadratic form of the form
$$
\langle 1,\ldots,1,d\rangle,
$$
where $d\in \mathbf F_q^\star/\mathbf F_q^{\star2}$ is the discriminant of $Q$, i.e., the determinant of its associated bilinear form (cf. O'Meara: Introduction to quadratic forms, p. 157). This is in fact not so difficult to prove. It follows from the statement that any nonsingular quadratic form of dimension $\geq2$ represents all elements of $\mathbf F_q^\star$, by splitting off quadratic forms of the form $\langle 1\rangle$ until you are left with $\langle d\rangle$. Anyway, since both of your quadratic forms are regular, of dimension $3$ and have discriminant equal to $1$, they are equivalent over any finite field $\mathbf F_q$ of characteristic different from $2$.

Answer (score 0):

One  can show that the form $y^2 + z^2$ can be transformed into $-(y^2+z^2)$, equivalently, there exists some matrix $A\in GL(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$ such that

$$A^t \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}\cdot A = \begin{pmatrix} -1&0 \\ 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & - b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$, so we only need $a^2 + b^2 = -1$, or

$$a^2 + b^2 + 1 =0$$

Equivalently, we need to show that the equation

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 0$$

has a non-zero solution, which follows from [Chevalley-Warning theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem).  ( one can also show directly  that $a^2 + b^2 = -1$  has a solution in $(a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_q^2)$